# Is there command line to deploy chrome extension for faster development?

Tags: google-chrome, deployment, google-chrome-extension

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html

In the docs,

it instructs we have to open the chrome:extesion page every time and load our own extension

is there any way to use command line such that i can do faster? 
(mac OS or linux)

Thanks

Comment: If you are loading a unpacked extension, then you can just hit `reload` on the extensions page and it will reload it. I think that is pretty fast as it is.

Comment: I haven't tried it out yet, but there is a grunt plugin that is supposed to do this for you: https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-chrome-extension-reload

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Go to the extension page, press ctrl+R, the original extension will be reloaded automatically and that doesn't need to do any import action any more.

Comment: question is about deploy

Answer (score 0):

Check out [chrome.runtime.reload()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-reload). I haven't used it myself, but I suppose you could put a button somewhere convenient and trigger that method with it.

Answer (score 0):

A team I am working with on a Chrome extension has figured out the following CHROME_RUN.py `Python` script:

```
cwd = sys.path[0]
CHROME_EXTENSION_DIR = cwd + "/Chrome-Extension"
TEMP_DIR = tempfile.mkdtemp()
TEMP_CHROME_PROFILE = TEMP_DIR + "/Chrome-Temp-Profile"

ccUrl = "PAGE_TO_OPEN.HTML"

if not os.path.exists(TEMP_DIR):
os.makedirs(TEMP_DIR)

FULL_CHROME_ARGS = "-user-data-dir=" + TEMP_CHROME_PROFILE + " --load-extension=" + CHROME_EXTENSION_DIR + " \"" +  ccUrl + "\"";

if _platform == "win32":
    os.system("BUILD_CHROME_PROJECT.py")
    os.system("start chrome " + "-user-data-dir=" + TEMP_CHROME_PROFILE + " --load-extension=" + CHROME_EXTENSION_DIR + " \"" +  ccUrl + "\"")
elif _platform == "darwin":
    os.system("python BUILD_CHROME_PROJECT.py")
    os.system("open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args " + "-user-data-dir=" + TEMP_CHROME_PROFILE + " --load-extension=" + CHROME_EXTENSION_DIR + " \"" +  ccUrl + "\"")
elif _platform == "linux" or _platform == "linux2":
    os.system("./BUILD_CHROME_PROJECT.py")
    os.system("chromium " + "-user-data-dir=" + TEMP_CHROME_PROFILE + " --load-extension=" + CHROME_EXTENSION_DIR + " \"" +  ccUrl + "\"")
shutil.rmtree(TEMP_DIR)
```

which is compatible with OSX, Windows and Linux.

If you are looking for the actual arguments to provide Chrome, it is as follows:

```
FULL_CHROME_ARGS = "-user-data-dir=" + TEMP_CHROME_PROFILE + " --load-extension=" + CHROME_EXTENSION_DIR + " \"" +  ccUrl + "\"";
```

It will creates a temporary profile and launches Chrome with the provided URL. This version of Chrome is similar to how FireFox sandboxes an instance of the browser for plugin testing (fresh, clean instance of the browser with history, cache, etc. from your browsing history)